# Is there any difference between template specialization of function and function with same interface as it, but without template specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization, function-templates

Suppose I have a template function and it's specialization.

```cpp
template<class T>
void myfunction(T whatever)
{
}

template<>
void myfunction(int whatever)
{
    //whatever
}
```

As far as I know, if I never call `myfunction` is the my programm, the template will never be instantiated and will go into the binary code only regarded as a template(correct me if I am wrong). My question is, will the specialization of `myfunction` be instantiated in this case?

If yes, how would it differ from the following definition of `myfunction`

```
void myfunction(int whatever)
{
    //This is the version of myfunction with the same interface as the template specialization of myfunction above, 
    //except it is not templated.
}
```

Comment: *how would it differ?* - You cannot call the latter with `myfunction<int>(42)`;

Comment: Possible/Probable duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16865225/10871073

Comment: If you ask which will be removed from binary when not used, it's easy enough to check: https://godbolt.org/z/aeWq3rxW7. If you are asking about general differences, see [Template Specialization VS Function Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading)

Comment: Well both the mentioned links answer my question, thank you.